# How to stand up then shut down a Solr instance in a Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, solr, jetty, apache-camel

I am writing camel unit test. One service that I interface with is Solr. After testing with mocks, I want to write tests that bring up a local solr instance.

So far I have tried to leverage the RestTestBase Solr class (org.apache.solr.util.RestTestBase). Because I am writing a unit test, I have not extended the class, merely tried to use the static methods it provides. The following does *not* work:

```
RestTestBase.createJettyAndHarness("src/test/resources/solr",
                                   "solrconfig.xml", "schema.xml",
                                   "/solr", true, null);
int solrPort = RestTestBase.jetty.getLocalPort();
String solrURL = "localhost:"+Integer.toString(solrPort)+"/solr";
...
```

I included solr and jetty in my pom. Any suggestions for how to programmatic stand up and shut down a solr instance? (because i am using camel unit testing, i prefer not to extend RestTestBase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the camel-solr unit tests for some complete examples....[SolrComponentTestSupport](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=camel.git;a=blob_plain;f=components/camel-solr/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/solr/SolrComponentTestSupport.java;hb=HEAD)

basically this...

```
@BeforeClass
public static void beforeClass() throws Exception {
    // Set appropriate paths for Solr to use.
    System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", "src/test/resources/solr");
    System.setProperty("solr.data.dir", "target/test-classes/solr/data");

    // Instruct Solr to keep the index in memory, for faster testing.
    System.setProperty("solr.directoryFactory", "solr.RAMDirectoryFactory");

    // Start a Solr instance.
    solrRunner = new JettySolrRunner("src/test/resources/solr", "/solr", getPort());
    solrRunner.start();

    solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:" + getPort() + "/solr");
}

@AfterClass
public static void afterClass() throws Exception {
    if (solrRunner != null) {
        solrRunner.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is exactly what i'm looking for. I'm running into an issue, however. When i try to interact with the solr instance (even using the included SolrUpdateTest along with all superclasses) i get the following error: 

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getDispatcherType()Lorg/eclipse/jetty/server/DispatcherType;`

When i sleep the thread in the unit test and try to open the Solr web console, it also triggers the same error. Any ideas?

Thanks again

Comment: my error was from a maven jetty dependency issue. Thanks for you answer. Just what i was looking for